# Problem with crystal oscillator based RF circuit

Tags: oscillator, modeling

As a little experiment, a friend and I are trying to get a crystal oscillator based transmitter and receiver to work. So far we're having no luck.

Here are the wiring diagrams:

[image]

[image]

We once got the transmitter to send on 27MHz, but with a very erratic signal.  We used a digital oscilloscope to verify. The wire wound inductor on the receiver is hand made from a ferrite core.

I have also been told that using a breadboard can add a capacitance effect and throw the crystal oscillator out of balance.  Is there any way to counter or compensate for this?

Comment: OP! Please check if the circuits are correct

Comment: To get a useful answer, you should probably add 1) what you want the circuits to do 2) what they are currently doing 3) what you have already done to troubleshoot the problem

Comment: So far we've checked the outputs got nothing from the receiver and 27MHz out the transmitter but the signal was zig-zag not square. We think the ferrite core is the right one and the coils need adjusting. cant get a square wave out the timer section on the transmitter. I think we might have 755s instead of 555 will this have significant difference.               Our source for the circuits is.  http://www.pyroelectro.com/projects/pyro_rf_receiver_27mhz/                                    and.          http://www.pyroelectro.com/projects/pyro_rf_transmitter_27mhz/